# Optimize a count query or restructure the design?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, aggregate-functions

Im trying to do report system by range date (from/to date) for products (around 30k products that will repetitive record in DB) viewed/clicked by users.

Each time user click on product i record product_id and date on single row in Database. My problem is coming when i have to select and display report because table quickly grow up to 4 millions in 2 months and i have to keep record up to 6 months.

My question is there any better way to optimize the query or the way i record them?

DB Table

```
CREATE TABLE `product_view` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `date_create` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `product_view`
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ADD KEY `product_id` (`product_id`) USING BTREE;
```

My select query without range date take around 50 seconds to pull results

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE pd.name, pv.product_id, p.model, COUNT(pv.id) as total
FROM product_view pv
    LEFT JOIN product p ON p.product_id = pv.product_id
    LEFT JOIN product_description pd ON pd.product_id = pv.product_id
WHERE pv.product_id > 0
GROUP BY pv.product_id
ORDER BY total
DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

Query EXAMPlE

```
id  select_type     table   type      possible_keys     key           key_len      ref                      rows        Extra
1   SIMPLE           pv     range   product_id           product_id     4         NULL                      1647717     Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE           p     eq_ref   PRIMARY              PRIMARY        4         test.pv.product_id        1
1   SIMPLE           pd     ref     PRIMARY,product_id   PRIMARY        4         test.pv.product_id        1
```

Query with range date

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE pd.name, pv.product_id, p.model, COUNT(pv.id) as total
FROM product_view pv
    LEFT JOIN product p ON p.product_id = pv.product_id
    LEFT JOIN product_description pd ON pd.product_id = pv.product_id
WHERE pv.product_id > 0
    AND DATE(pv.date_create) >= '2021-07-25'
    AND DATE(pv.date_create) <= '2022-03-10'
GROUP BY pv.product_id
ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

Comment: You showed us the definition and indexes for `product_view` but what about `product` and `product_description`? Those need indexes as well. If there's not an index on each of `product_description.product_id` and `product.product_id`, then each row in `product_view` is going to have to do two table scans to do the JOINs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rewriting the query as a correlated query:

```
select p.product_id, p.model, pd.name, (
    select count(*)
    from product_view as pv
    where pv.product_id = p.product_id
    and pv.date_create >= '2021-07-25'
    and pv.date_create <  '2022-03-10' + interval 1 day
) as total
from product as p
left join product_description as pd on p.product_id = pd.product_id
where exists (
    select 1
    from product_view as pv
    where pv.product_id = p.product_id
    and pv.date_create >= '2021-07-25'
    and pv.date_create <  '2022-03-10' + interval 1 day
    -- this is a far more optimized version for dates used in your op
)
order by total desc
limit 0, 20
```

This does not involve grouping so it *should* be faster than your original query. If date filter is not required then remove the `where exists` part and `and pv.date_create ...` from the count sub-query.

Secondly, I don't see any useful indexes in the explain. You should *try* the following indexes:

```
create index ix1 on product_view (product_id, date_create)
-- should be (i) good for joining (ii) "covers" the date column
```

Comment: shouldn't i group them ? because at the end report must look like: product_id = 10 , total view: 30000, product_id = 20, total view: 2000

Comment: No. The grouping (implicit grouping because of count(\*)) is done in the sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `product_view` (
-- toss, as useless:  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`date_create` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(product_id, date_create)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(date_create))` to make the deletion much more efficient.  I recommend about 30 weekly partitions.  See [*Partition*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) .

`COUNT(pv.id)` -- The usual pattern is simply `COUNT(*)`.  With an id, it checks that id for being `NOT NULL`, which is unnecessary.

`pv.product_id > 0` -- is there something special about ids <=0?

Let's rearrange the query to "start" with the count:

```
SELECT pd.name, pv.product_id, p.model, s.total
    FROM ( SELECT pv.product_id, COUNT(*) AS total
             FROM product_view AS pv
             WHERE pv.date_create >= '2021-07-25'
         ) AS s
    JOIN product AS p  ON p.product_id = pv.product_id
    ORDER BY total DESC
    LIMIT 0, 20
```

Note:

- Get rid of `DATE()`, it is not "sargable" and prevents the use of any index.
- If you want the count to go through yesterday, then add
  `AND pv.date_create < CURDATE()`
- `LEFT` implies that the 'right' row may be missing; I suspect that is not the case.
- I got rid of `pd` since it is not used (and costs a lot to have if it won't be used).
- `SQL_NO_CACHE` is going away in 8.0; you may as well turn off the Query cache now.
- If the date range goes back through most of the data, the entire table will be scanned, so I have not helped performance much in that area.  So...
- Build and maintain a Summary Table with (dy, product_id, subtotal); then do the query against it.  See [*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)